# Replace a gridview row while rendering

Tags: gridview, overriding, row, render

I've got a datatable bound to a gridview and in the RowDataBound event I check the values of the fields to determine what to show in the gridview row.

However, in some cases I want to show a row with just a single label that spans all columns, when the data values in the row can't be calculated.

Is there a way to override the rendering of a single row when a gridview is bound to remove/add controls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) event.